# Semicolon in namespace. Necessary?

Tags: c++, namespaces

when working with namespace, I need to finish it with a semicolon? When I put a forward declaration of a class into a namespace, for example, many people doesn't include a semicolon but, it seems to be optional.

Does semicolon add functionality or change the current functionality by adding or removing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you pls edit to include samples of what you mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If semicolon is optional it doesn't change functionality, otherwise it you omit it you'll get a syntax error.

```
namespace A {
    class B; // forward declaration, semicolon is mandatory.

    class B {
    }; // class definition, semicolon is mandatory

    class C {
    } f(); // because otherwise it is a return type of a function.
} // no need for semicolon

namespace D = A; // semicolon is mandatory.
```

If these are not the cases you talked about, comment please.

Comment: When you say "no need for semicolon", any semicolon is illegal in C++03.

Comment: @Charles: Are you sure? In C++0x and C++98 *simple-declaration* can degenerate to `;` (everything else marked *opt*).

Comment: Yes, check 7 [dcl.dcl] paragraph 3. In a _simple-declaration_ the optional init-declarator-list can be omitted only when declaring a class or enumeration, ... . Basically, the _init-declarator-list_ can be omitted only when _decl-specifier-seq_ isn't.

Comment: It is, of course, legal in C++0x as there is a new type of _declaration_, the _empty-declaration_ which consists of just a `;` and explicitly has no effect. Personally, I don't see the point of using an _empty-declaration_.

Comment: @Charles: thanks for the info. You may use it when you generate code with e.g. macros and sometimes it expands to nothing.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I'm not sure I can think of an example where it would be necessary to generate a single (only legal in the future) `;` instead of nothing. Or did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: It's marginally useful, as it makes `int a;;` legal. Consider a macro `#define DECLARE_MEMBER(x) int x;`, unintentionally used as `DECLARE_MEMBER(a);`

Answer (score 8):

No. Namespaces do not need to end with a semicolon though [Bjarne wanted to do it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1993/N0262.pdf) I guess to reduce syntax related discrepancies with other C++ constructs. However I am not sure why it was not accepted.

> "Silly typing errors will inevitably
>   arise from the syntactic similarity of
>   the namespace constructs to other C++
>   constructs. I propose we allow an
>   optional semicolon after a global
>   declaration to lessen the frustration.
>   This would be a kind of ‘‘empty
>   declaration’’ to match the empty
>   statements."

All forward declarations of the class need to end with a semicolon. Can you give examples of where it is optional in C++?

Comment: I think that bruce eckel recommends to end with a semicolon to enforce the idea of an isolated block

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to "finish it" with a semi-colon. It is not common practice, nor does it have any effect.

```
namespace foo
{
    ...
} // no semi-colon necessary here.
```