# Symbol 'A' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, oop, header, eclipse-cdt

I have this problem Symbol 'A' could not be resolved in file B.h , I'm using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers:

```
//B.h file

#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include "A.h"



class B:  public cs::A{

};

#endif
```

that include A.h file:

```
//A.h file

#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_
namespace cs{
class A {


};
}

#endif
```

What I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 5):

You placed the class `A` inside a namespace, you should keep the namespace resolution while using it:

```
class B:  public cs::A{

};
```

Or

```
//B.h file

#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include "A.h"

using namespace cs;

class B:  public A{

};

#endif
```

Which isn't recommended (check Als's comment).

Also you can do this to avoid both keeping the whole namespace qualification every time you use `A` (which you should do in the first solution), and `using` all the namespace:

```
//B.h file

#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include "A.h"

using cs::A;

class B:  public A{

};

#endif
```

Comment: `using namespace cs;` is definitely an overkill and should be avoided especially in an header file.It imports all the symbols in the namespace `cs` in each translation unit where the header file will be included.

Comment: @Als: I agree with you, that's why I said I don't recommend it. However, I managed to view it and then unrecommend it to notify about the badness of that :)

Comment: I did add `using namespace cs;` and I got Symbol 'cs' could not be resolved, when I used `class B:  public cs::A{};` I got "Symbol 'A' could not be resolved" ?!

Comment: @nabil: You missed a semicolon, check the added part of the answer.

Comment: thank you, but I still have the same problem, it seems that in file B.h "Symbol 'cs' could not be resolved"

Comment: @nabil: There is something wrong with your code that's not included in the snippet you posted, perhaps you have some class/namespace that you've not closed correctly before `cs`, and so the `cs` is not directly visible in `B.h`.

Comment: I just want to point out that namespaces don't have to end with a semicolon. In fact, my compiler complains when you do put one there due to the `pedantic` flag.

Comment: @chris: [You are right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3849900/368167), will fix it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
class B: public cs::A{ };
                ^^^^^^
```

You need to provide the fully qualified name of class `A`.

Note that the class `A` is defined inside the namespace `cs` and hence you cannot just use `A` without namespace qualification.

Comment: it does not solve the problem, Symbol 'A' could not be resolved !

Answer (score 0):

You are using namespace cs, remember to use that again when declaring class B.

```
//B.h file

#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include "A.h"


class B:  public cs::A{

};

#endif
```