# A' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have this problem Symbol 'A' could not be resolved in file B.h , I'm using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers:

```
//B.h file

#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include "A.h"



class B:  public cs::A{

};

#endif
```

that include A.h file:

```
//A.h file

#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_
namespace cs{
class A {


};
}

#endif
```

What I'm missing here ?

Comment: Is this an eclipse complaint or a compiler error? If eclipse, did you try compiling?

Comment: works fine for me with g++ 4.6.4 on Windows. Is this all the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbol 'A' could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461031/symbol-a-could-not-be-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code. Most likely your include path is incorrect.

```
#pragma message ("Parsing A.h")
```